# Database Schema guidance for an app store

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I am creating a sample project and want to demonstrate a small app store functionality. 
I need a basic database schema to start. Are the database schema (ER diagrams) available for any of the stores (Apple App Store or Google Play)?

I am just looking for schema examples that I can refer to.

Answer (score 4):

**Apple** and **Google** are not releasing a public documentation of their backend architecture for their respective *app stores*. Although there are a few examples of actual data model for this scenario easily found using Google, for instance [Barry Williams](http://uk.linkedin.com/pub/barry-williams/17/a6b/192) produced [this small sample](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/cell_mobile_apps_stores/index.htm) of a mobile app store's data model.

This would answer your question to get an example of schema for an *app store*. but as I'm pretty sure such a task would be more efficiently achieved by actually starting from scratch than adapting an existing model. I would recommend you have a look at [basic modeling strategies](https://www.google.ca/#q=978-1423900832+), to further your skills in data modeling, you probably will quickly find its pretty easy to do.

Good luck with your sample project and don't hesitate to comment if you have further questions!